# How to Assign Ajax data value to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hiii Everyone,

My PHP Code

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
require "country.php";
$per_email=$_POST['per_email'];
$stream_name=$_POST['specialization_filter'];
$country_filter=$_POST['country_filter'];
$country = new country();
$users = $country->universities($stream_name,$country_filter);

if ( empty($users) ) {
?>
<br/><br/>
   <?php       echo "<span class=\"alert alert-danger\">No universities Available For Your Search Results!!! </span> <br>" ;

}else{

 ?>
<div class="table-responsive" id="filter_universities">
<table class="table no-border">
<thead >
<tr class="row_univ">
<th class="university_sort" id="name_total_sort" status="asc" style="cursor:pointer">University 
<i class="fa fa-caret-down font-grey-salsa"></i>
</th>
<th class="col-md-3">Program</th>
<th class="fee_structure" id="fee_total_sort" status="asc" style="cursor:pointer">Fee 
<i class="fa fa-caret-down font-grey-salsa"></i>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

$i=0;
 foreach ($users as $user){ 
$i++;
?>
        <tr class="tr_bgs">
        <td class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="images/university1.jpg" class="img-circle" width="62px" height="62px" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <h5 class="bold fees">
        <a target="_blank" class="university_class" mode="ambitious" cid="292"><?php echo $user['university']?> </a>
        </h5>
        <span class="font-grey-lite"><?php echo $user['country']?> </span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <h5 class="bold fees"><?php echo $user['course']?> </h5>
        <span class="font-grey-lite"> 
        <?php echo $user['stream_name']?> </span>
        </td>
        <td>
        <h5 class="bold fees"><?php echo $user['fees']?> </h5>
        <span class="font-grey-lite">Per Year</span>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
 <div id="added_course<?php echo $user['id']; ?>"><br/><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="delete_course_list(<?php echo $user['id']?>);">
 <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Course Added</button></div>
 <div id="add_course<script alert(<?php echo $user['id']?>);></script>">              
 <br/><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
 onClick="save_course_list(<?php echo $user['id']?>);">
 <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Add to My Course</button></div></td>
</tr>   
<tr class="row_univ tr_bgs">
<td colspan="6">
<table class="table no-border no-margin text-grey">
<tbody>
<tr class="tr_bgs">

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>  
<?php
 } 
          }  ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>
  function save_course_list(str)
  {
    var course_id=str;
    var per_email= '<?php echo $per_email; ?>' ;
    var datas="&course_id="+course_id+"&per_email="+per_email;
    alert(datas);
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'php/country/add_course.php',
    data:datas
    }).done(function( data ) 
    {
      alert(data);
      $('#added_course<?php echo $user["id"];?>').show();
      $('#add_course<?php echo $user["id"];?>').hide();    
      });

  }
  function delete_course_list(str)
  {
    var course_id=str;
    var per_email= '<?php echo $per_email; ?>' ;
    var datas="&course_id="+course_id+"&per_email="+per_email;
    alert(datas);
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'php/country/delete_course.php',
    data:datas
    }).done(function( data ) 
    {
      alert(data);
   $('#added_course<?php echo $user["id"]?>').hide();
   $('#add_course<?php echo $user["id"]?>').show();    
      });

  }
</script>
```

And My Example UI Page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ2HS.png)

Based On selection Of Country and specialization

```
$users = $country->universities($stream_name,$country_filter);
```

this function will retrieve university details from database and onclick of add course it will retrieve particular userid and save in database and also i want hide add course button and i want to display course added button but what happening here is.while click on add course it will hide last user_id because script is outside of foreach loop so the value which is getting will be last modified in php.So that what i want to do is.

```
 $('#added_course<?php echo $user["id"];?>').show();
```

instead od $user['id'] i want to pass data value return in ajax how can i do this.Please anyone help me to get out of this problem.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does `alert(data);` shows?

Comment: i just checked whether returned value is correct or not by alert(data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the save_course_list function, now you pass the corresponding id to backed php . Then you just pass this value to ajax response and use

Comment: Now i tried like that only..but it is taking last updated userid value for example in case of singapore and arts and communication selection it filtered 4 universities among this wherever i press button it hide and show last userid.this is the issue im facing now @Anish

Comment: Can u tell your explanation in code I cant understand actually

Comment: Ok you can include ajax response with last updated id and passing user id. can u specify the current response of ajax call

Comment: Instead of hiding corresponding id's button its hiding last updated id's button @Anish

Comment: $('#added_course'+data).show();
      $('#add_course'+data).hide(); here data means ajax response id from php side

Comment: You passed the clicked button id to php through ajax call, then collect that id from response and use

Comment: But one more problem is happend now.

Comment: If i add one more condition like if else before that td div button this button is not showing hiding